# Remove orphaned Inode (LVM) without unmount or restart

Tags: inode

One of our VM hard disk is getting full and the only way to fix it is to restart it. Upon restarting it, we can see it is removing orphaned Inodes and once its done, the VM is ok due to its disk space is getting freed.
This happens every now and then and the only way to free it up is to restart it, however I need a way to remove orphaned Inodes (on ex4 disk) without unmounting the drive or restarting the VM on Centos 6.5.

This is the screen shot of orphan inodes removal messages on the restart https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tM3A.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: LVM does not have inodes. It's also not a filesystem. So you haven't explained what filesystem you are using. You also haven't explained why you think orphaned inodes are causing you a problem.

Comment: I have corrected it and provided more details

Comment: Orphaned inodes are not your problem, they're a symptom of an unclean restart of the system.  Something else is causing your problems.

Comment: Any idea how can I narrow it down? ( checked the logs but nothing useful)